# Simpler/cleaner way to specify ranges when using lots of named cells in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

In a fairly large Excel program I'm working on, I have a lot of named cells in the spreadsheets that get filled with data in order to help keep formatting consistent if the user ever decides to move the template setup around, and to avoid hardcoding row/column numbers in the various subs. Unfortunately, this leads to lots of ugly looking range references in my code, examples below. Is there a simpler/cleaner looking, more easily readable way to write these that I am missing?

```
'Examples of ugly range references:
Range(Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + m), -1), Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + m), 2))

Range(Range("GS_BeginData").Offset(counter, 1), Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + fileCount), 1))

Range("SS_Unit", Range("SS_Unit").Offset(0, 1))

Range("SS_BeginData", Range("SS_BeginData").End(xlDown))

Cells((Range("SS_BeginData").Row + i), (Range("SS_BeginData").Column + 1))
```

I suppose I could always set simply named variables to these various named cells and ranges at the beginning of the Subs to clean up the appearance of the code, but I have quite a bit of them and don't really want to add tons of lines of variable declarations to the beginning of all my Subs.

Comment: Have you considered using range or string variables in your range references?

Comment: You could load all the named ranges into more manegable variables. `Set GSBD = Range("GS_BeginData")`.  Then all you need to use is the variable.

Comment: You guys are fast! As I just added in the edit to the original post, I have quite a few of them and would rather not have line after line of variable declarations at the beginning of my Subs, but if there isn't another way I guess that will have to work.

Comment: Why don't you use a Table? You can reference parts of it almost like you would reference a table in a database.

Comment: You could really clean it up using [`With` Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Combine that with @ScottCraner's suggestion to set `Range` variables, and you're on your way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*more easily readable way* -- yes. Declare and assign object variables as may be required. At a minimum, you can define ranges for "GS_BeginData" and "SS_Unit" and "SS_BeginData" which would make your code more readable and maintainable.

This way, if you ever change the *names* of your named range references, you only need to update a few short lines of code that assign to the initial objects, instead of every literal reference e.g., to `"GS_BeginData"`, etc.

```
Dim GSBegin as Range, SSBegin as Range, SSUnit as Range

Set GSBegin = Range("GS_BeginData")
Set SSBegin = Range("SS_BeginData")
Set SSUnit = Range("SS_Unit")
```

Then, your ugly references can be modified:

```
Range(GSBegin.Offset((counter + m), -1), GSBegin.Offset((counter + m), 2))

Range(GSBegin.Offset(counter, 1), GSBegin.Offset((counter + fileCount), 1))

SSUnit.Offset(0, 1)

Range(SSBegin, SSBegin.End(xlDown))

Cells((SSBegin.Row + i), (SSBegin.Column + 1))
```

Comment: He could even add `With GSBegin` before those first two lines, and then `End With` just before the end, no?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes of course, and as ChrisNielsen points out the `Resize` method is also valuable in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use variables! (`Dim`'s are a small price to pay)
2. Leverage other Range properties.  In these cases `Resize` is useful

.

```
Dim GS_BeginData As Range
Set GS_BeginData = Range("GS_BeginData")
'Set r = Range(Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + m), -1), Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + m), 2))
Set r = GS_BeginData.Offset(counter + m, -1).Resize(, 3)

'Set r = Range(Range("GS_BeginData").Offset(counter, 1), Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + fileCount), 1))
Set r = GS_BeginData.Offset(counter, 1).Resize(fileCount, 1)

Dim SS_Unit As Range
Set SS_Unit = Range("SS_Unit")
'Set r = Range("SS_Unit", Range("SS_Unit").Offset(0, 1))
Set r = SS_Unit.Resize(, 2)
Set r = SS_Unit.Resize(, SS_Unit.Columns.Count + 1) ' if SS_Unit has more than 1 column

Dim SS_BeginData As Range
Set SS_BeginData = Range("SS_BeginData")
'Set r = Range("SS_BeginData", Range("SS_BeginData").End(xlDown))
Set r = Range(SS_BeginData, SS_BeginData.End(xlDown))

'Set r = Cells((Range("SS_BeginData").Row + i), (Range("SS_BeginData").Column + 1))
Set r = SS_BeginData.Offset(i, 1).Resize(1, 1)
```

Comment: Dim As Range will also be faster if you are calling Range() multiple times, since Range() will be get dynamically, while the variable will directly point to the Range object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using it in a number of different Subs you could also make a function to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) up your code, like.

```
Function GSBeginOffsetRange(a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long) As Range
    Dim GSBegin As Range
    Set GSBegin = Range("GS_BeginData")
    Set GSBeginOffsetRange = Range(GSBegin.Offset(a, b), GSBegin.Offset(c, d))
End Function
```

This would make your first line example:

```
GSBeginOffsetRange((counter + m), -1, (counter + m), 2)
```

Comment: Good one, DRY is very usefill skill to learn (or a motto to live by, really). One comment. Using Integer variables is not usefull. Although Integers use less memory then Long variables, the compiler converts the Integers to Longs, so no memory win after all. The compiler needs to convert, so you pay a small perfomance price. On top of that all, writing the word 'Integer' in your code takes more time then 'Long' ;-).

Comment: Good point. Didn't know about compiler converting Integer to Long. :-)

Comment: @jzz not only that, you can't access the whole sheet with in Integer

Comment: How is this DRY, when all it does is repeats the offset functionality?

Comment: This is repeating `Range(Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + m), -1), Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + m), 2))` and `Range(Range("GS_BeginData").Offset(counter, 1), Range("GS_BeginData").Offset((counter + fileCount), 1))`

Comment: GSBeginOffsetRange will prevent to repeat `Range(Range, Range)` stuff which is a complicated syntax that will become difficult to maintain. GSBeginOffsetRange is certainly easier to maintain.

Comment: Also if he changes GS_BeginData name for any reason he will only have to change it once in the code. And he can reuse the function across different subroutines while Dim cannot, although I know Dim will perform better, it is not an issue if it is not in a while loop or something.

Comment: The developer should create functions to DRY up code which will best fit its needs, I don't have access to his code to do so, this is just a silly example which will satisfy the question "Simpler/cleaner way to specify ranges when using lots of named cells in VBA?". Can't state it isn't simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply list all the Named Rnages and then loop through each item in that list?

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/44907-list-out-named-ranges-visual-basic-applications.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't use named ranges because they are difficult to maintain and soon become a mess. I always use these two functions:

```
Function RowNumber(Header As String, _
             Optional Sh As Worksheet, _
             Optional FromColumn As Integer = 1, _
             Optional IgnoreError As Boolean = False) As Integer
  If Sh Is Nothing Then Set Sh = ActiveSheet

  Dim R As Integer
  For R = 1 To Sh.UsedRange.Row + Sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    If Sh.Cells(R, FromColumn) = Header Then RowNumber = R: Exit Function
  Next R

  If Not IgnoreError Then MsgBox "Row """ & Header & """ not found", vbCritical
End Function

Function ColumnNumber(Header As String, _
             Optional Sh As Worksheet, _
             Optional FromRow As Integer = 1, _
             Optional IgnoreError As Boolean = False) As Integer
  If Sh Is Nothing Then Set Sh = ActiveSheet

  Dim C As Integer
  For C = 1 To Sh.UsedRange.Column + Sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
    If Sh.Cells(FromRow, C) = Header Then ColumnNumber = C: Exit Function
  Next C

  If Not IgnoreError Then MsgBox "Column """ & Header & """ not found", vbCritical
End Function
```

Then I get the value with something like:

```
Value = Sh.Cells(RowNumber("Header", Sh), 2)
```

I sometimes use another version with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).